# Table designer (Entity Framework) is too resource intense

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm working on a project that we're using .NET MVC 3 and EF 4. The website is growing and there are a lot of tables. So, the table designer of Entity Framework too much CPU usage t open and add new tables. What are my options? What can I do?

Comment: You mean, the Entity Model designer within Visual Studio requires too much CPU usage?

Comment: Is this about EF 5 or 4? Your title says 5, but the tags, 4.

Comment: Don't use the designer. It's a crutch anyway, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

For larger models, I think the designer approach is less desirable. If you can, consider refactoring (one bite at a time?) to a code-first approach; this will allow you to keep using current technology. I have a project with ~650 entities working perfectly fine, but I can't imagine loading a .edmx designer with ~650 entities (without pulling my hair, that is).

All in all, it's not EF that's "heavy" - it's the designer.

Comment: You're using EF code-first?

Comment: Since Entity Framework 4.1 made it an option, yes! There are tools out there, to reverse-engineer an existing database into a code-first model. Could be your easy way out :)

Comment: I think it's a good idea, I'll read about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Visual Studio 2012, you can now split your Entity Model **into multiple diagrams**. This'll reduce the diagram complexity a lot.

See

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721589.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj519700.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you database operations are large in general you may consider not using EF and use raw ADO.NET instead. EF boils down to ADO.NET at the low level anyway but using ADO.NET right away will improve performance.

Comment: The "transaction" from EF to ADO .NET is complicated?

Comment: You mean "transition" - the major downside is that you lose all the abstraction provided by EF, and end up using an outdated technology that, to be used cleanly, would require implementing *repository* and *unit of work* yourself - which the EF `DbContext` does.

Comment: This is a bit drastic, wouldn't you say? The problem is with the designer not EF itself.

Answer (score 1):

Moving to a code first architecture is definitely something to consider for the long term. For the short term, you also might be able to break your model up into multiple design contexts. You can start this by identifying areas of the application that only use a subset of the tables. Then create a separate data context that only includes those tables. You can keep the existing omnibus context around while you're working on this to avoid breaking legacy code. You can add as many data contexts as you like, but I would create each one in a separate folder (and therefore a separate namespace) so you don't have to worry about name collisions.